# Phone as Bluetooth Headset

Tags: audio, java-me, bluetooth, headset

I need my phone to act like a Bluetooth headset.
I am planning to run a J2ME application in Phone to make Phone as Bluetooth Headset.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: didnt get my answer yet.

Comment: Look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16873447/2437881)

I hope to help you...

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done in J2ME as the [Bluetooth API](http://www.jsr82.com) supports only SPP and L2CAP (and occasionally OBEX).  Bluetooth headsets require the [Headset profile](http://www.bluetooth.com/English/Technology/Works/pages/hsp.aspx).