# How to Text-to-Speech plays on Bluetooth in Android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-audiomanager, bluetooth-sco

I'm a newbie for android. I've created an app that can read Incoming messages using Android Text-To-Speech. Up to now its fine with it. Now user's want It has to play over paired Bluetooth.

I'd read all the forums but i didn't get it. Now how i play my TTS engine on Bluetooth ?

Anyone having any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use my answer at [Using the Android RecognizerIntent with a bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset/14993590#14993590)

And create a speak method like below

```
protected void speak(String text)
{

    HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();

    if (mBluetoothHelper.isOnHeadsetSco())
    {
        myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, 
                String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL));
    }
    mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashRender);
}
```

Comment: mBluetoothHelper cannot be resolved to a variable in my MainActivity

Comment: Did you copy the BluetoothHeadsetUtils in the above link to your project?

Comment: Yes i copied, Because of the error i converted your two lines into 

BluetoothHeadsetUtils mBluetoothHelper = new BluetoothHeadsetUtils(this);

Comment: I fixed the error there. It should be BluetoothHeadsetUtils mBluetoothHelper; and then the other line is correct. The mBluetoothHelper should be a class member in your class. You declare it as a local variable, that why you got the error.

Comment: I made a slight modification to the BluetoothHeadsetUtils class about an hour ago. Make sure you get the latest update. If you have mIsStarted in the class then you are up to date.

Comment: Ok i will follow. If no bluetooth is connected is your code connects to debugger that showing message ?

Comment: I do not quite understand what do you mean? Do you mean is there a way to find out if there is no connected headset?

Comment: That's file i will take care of it. Anyway thank you for your time. If i have any questions further i will post here.