# Modify speech recognition without popup

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I'm totally new to Android and I decided to create a Siri look-a-like app, which is working fine, I searched before asking but I can't get it to work: [Android speech Recognition App Without Pop Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228817/android-speech-recognition-app-without-pop-up)

So I want to hide the pop-up inside my Android app, but I really don't now how to do it properly. I'll be very glad if someone could help me doing this. I have already added the correct permissions in Android Manifest...

Here is my full source:

```
/**
 * Giovanni Terlingen
 * PWS Project
 * 3 november 2014
 * Original file from http://github.com/gi097/PWS
 */
package nl.giovanniterlingen.pws;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnInitListener {
    private static final String TAG = "PWS";

    private TextView result;

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    private Button speak;

    private int SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        speak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_speak);
        speak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendRecognizeIntent();
            }
        });

        speak.setEnabled(false);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            speak.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            // failed to init
            finish();
        }

    }

    private void sendRecognizeIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Aan het luisteren...");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 100);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                ArrayList<String> matches = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                if (matches.size() == 0) {
                    tts.speak("Ik heb niks gehoord, probeer het nog eens",
                            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                } else {
                    String mostLikelyThingHeard = matches.get(0);
                    result.setText("Dit heeft u gezegd: "
                            + mostLikelyThingHeard + ".");
                    mostLikelyThingHeard = mostLikelyThingHeard.toLowerCase();
                    boolean found = false;

                    String[] groeten = { "hallo", "heey", "hoi", "hey", "he",
                            "hee", "hay" };
                    for (String strings : groeten) {
                        if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
                            tts.speak("Hey leuk dat je er bent!",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    String[] okay = { "oké, oke, ok, okay, okee" };
                    for (String strings : okay) {
                        if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
                            tts.speak("Okiedokie!",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    String[] vragen = { "hoe gaat het", "hoe gaat het met je", "hoe gaat het met jou", "hoe gaat het met u", "hoe is het"};
                    for (String strings : vragen) {
                        if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
                            tts.speak("Met mij gaat het altijd goed, met jou?",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    String[] wie = { "wie ben", "hoe heet je", "hoe heet jij", "wat is je naam", "wat is uw naam"};
                    for (String strings : wie) {
                        if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
                            tts.speak("Ik ben PWS, ik ben gemaakt als profielwerkstuk door Giovanni Terlingen.",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    String[] leeftijd = { "hoe oud ben" };
                    for (String strings : leeftijd) {
                        if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
                            tts.speak("Ik ben op 3 november 2014 van start gegaan dus dat mag je zelf uitrekenen",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    String[] lachen = { "haha", "hah", "ha" };
                    for (String strings : okay) {
                        if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
                            tts.speak("Haha leuk grapje",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!found) {
                        String doei = "doei";
                        if (mostLikelyThingHeard.equals(doei)) {
                            tts.speak("Okay tot de volgende keer!",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        } else {
                            tts.speak("Ik begrijp niet wat je bedoeld met "
                                    + mostLikelyThingHeard
                                    + " probeer het anders te verwoorden.",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "result NOT ok");
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

In Android Manifest.xml, add the permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

**Step 2** 
In the Layout screen, i am using a Toggle Button to start/stop voice listening.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   .......

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

......

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Step 3 -** Activity Class

package com.example.voice;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class VoiceRecognitionActivity extends Activity implements
        RecognitionListener {

    private TextView returnedText;
    private ToggleButton toggleButton;

    private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
    private Intent recognizerIntent;
    private String LOG_TAG = "VoiceRecognitionActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        returnedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

        speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
        recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
                "en");
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                this.getPackageName());
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);

        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {

                    speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
                } else {
                                                                                    speech.stopListening();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (speech != null) {
            speech.destroy();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroy");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
                }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int errorCode) {
        String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
        returnedText.setText(errorMessage);
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEvent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResults");
        ArrayList<String> matches = results
                .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        String text = "";
        for (String result : matches)
            text += result + "\n";

        returnedText.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
    }

    public static String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
        String message;
        switch (errorCode) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            message = "Audio recording error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            message = "Client side error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            message = "Insufficient permissions";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            message = "Network error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            message = "Network timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            message = "No match";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            message = "RecognitionService busy";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            message = "error from server";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            message = "No speech input";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
            break;
        }
        return message;
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay well I tried already but I need to merge it in my source code properly :p