# Android speech recognition without keyboard

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is it possible to call the feature "speech to text" in the android keyboard without having to invoke the keyboard. I mean can I use another button to call the same feature. How do I do that?. Any suggestions?

Comment: Its basically firing an intent and you can definitely do with custom button. Check Google for the intent name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android speech Recognition App Without Pop Up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228817/android-speech-recognition-app-without-pop-up)