# Android TTS how to prevent popup asking about high quality file

Tags: android, popup, text-to-speech, galaxy

I am developing an app using the TextToSpeech class. I'm getting this pop-up on Galaxy Note 4 (Android 5.0) when calling Android's TextToSpeech.speak(...) that asks if I want to download a better quality voice file:

[High quality TTS Popup on Android 5, Galaxy S4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge6eb.png)

This didn't occur on the other development device, an ASUS tablet. How can I somehow prevent this popup from appearing when I use speech to text?

Searching around hasn't revealed much from a development perspective about this popup, or how to prevent it from appearing. I have checked here but it references recording audio and seems to reference a different issue: [Android speech Recognition App Without Pop Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228817/android-speech-recognition-app-without-pop-up)

On this particular device I could prevent it by simply accepting the download. That is evident from this, though I have not tried it: http://androidforums.com/threads/download-high-quality-voice-file.789236/ However, when installed on a new device, by the time the speech feature is enabled, the user may not have access to the device. It is a unique case, I suppose, violating normal guidelines for UI. Once the app starts, the user cannot be expected to interact with the app. It receives messages over the internet and speaks those, and this is when the popup appears.

I'm open to solutions that enable me to check and download the referenced high quality voice file myself (in order to prevent the popup, hopefully) and only start speaking once this is handled.

`mTextSpeech.speak(s2, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);`

EDIT:

Is there an INTENT sent somewhere in the loop that the Samsung package is responding to? My thinking is, I could check to see if the "offending" package causing the pop-up is in the PackageManager list, and then possibly go from there. Or if the package has been somehow registered with the system, maybe I could somehow un-register it? I admit I'm reaching here, but I'm sick of seeing this pop-up!