# Android offline speech recognition without a pop up dialog

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, android-speech-api

I have followed this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16229256/3024565) and created an activity. Now on click of a button I start speech recognition but it returns with error "ERROR_SERVER" as soon as I click on the button, It simply does not listen. It does not make any difference if I am connected to internet or not.

I have researched a lot but there is no proper documentation about the error codes nor any approach to resolve these errors. Hope someone can help me out here!

Comment: If no one can answer or comment better not discourage programmers by downvoting. At least have some guts to say something before down voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue on my own, so thanks but no thanks to the person down voting.

Note for people struggling with a similar issue, it is device dependent; may occur some devices or may not on others.
Please check the device voice input is set to Google or Basic Google recognition and not Enhanced Google Services. This seems to create issues on some devices.