# how to repeat an activity in another class from a view class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-view

I need to repeat an activity in another class from my current view class.

I m developing a simple voice controlled maze game application. I need to start speech recognition activity in another class(voice class) from the current View class. The voice class accepts voice input from the user,saves it in a variable and returns to the view class. The view is changed based on the input obtained from the of voice class. This has to be repeated till the cursor reaches the final position in the maze.

How can I repeat this voice activity from view class?  The view with new change has to be displayed for a short time before starting the activity again.

This is the function which I have to repeat. The voice activity is called from this function using context.

```
    public boolean voice_input() {
    int result;
    result = 0;
    boolean moved = false;
    try{

          Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex){

    }
    Context context = getContext();
    Intent i = new Intent(context, voice.class);
    ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(i,requestCode);
    result = v.getVariable();
    switch(result) {
        case 1:
            moved = maze.move(Maze.UP);
            break;
        case 2:
            moved = maze.move(Maze.DOWN);
            break;
        case 3:
            moved = maze.move(Maze.RIGHT);
            break;
        case 4:
            moved = maze.move(Maze.LEFT);
            break;  
    }
    result = 0;
    if(moved) {

        invalidate();

            if(maze.isGameComplete()) {
                showFinishDialog();
            }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is the activity in the voice class which has to be repeated.

```
     public void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
    {      
     match = 0;
     final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
     Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
     startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        match = 0;
        if (matches.contains("left")) {
            match = 4;
        }
        if (matches.contains("right")) {
            match = 3;
        }
        if (matches.contains("up")) {
            match = 1;
        }
        if (matches.contains("down")) {
            match = 2;
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, the best way to tackle this problem is to run Speech Recognition as a service. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219601/how-to-make-google-voice-run-continually-in-the-background-on-android).