# Voice recognition with bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

I have an app which uses voice recognition and tts. I want to use this app through bluetooth headset. I used code from this question: [Using the Android RecognizerIntent with a bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset)

Unfotunately, it did not work for me neither recording nor playing. I added in startBluetooth11 method:

```
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

This make recording working. But still can't get microphone to work.

Comment: @ladata, did you manage to solve the problem? I am facing the same problem, the voice recognition simply times out, it seems it is trying to get hold of the Bluetooth microphone but couldn't reach it. I am surprised it didn't route to the Phone microphone in case if it didn't get hold of the Bluetooth microphone.

Comment: @Harish, sorry I didn't cope with this :( Please let me know if you manage to solve it.