# Android: TTS to Bluetooth HFP

Tags: bluetooth, text-to-speech

New to Android programming.

Gone through the examples but not able to find the example for TTS text to Bluetooth HFP.

Seeing the TTS example to read the text and Bluetooth Example to find/list paired devices. But looking for the combined one to read the TTS text in Bluetooth HFP.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset/14993590#14993590