# Android startBluetoothSco() not working

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am on a LG phone (L38C) running android 2.3.6. I am having trouble obtaining audio input from bluetooth headset programatically. This seems to be a common issue but my research did not lead to any solutions.  I have tried the solution proposed here but the CO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED event is not triggered.

[Using the Android RecognizerIntent with a bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset/14993590#14993590)

Any thoughts?

PS: My headset (JABRA BT2046) is paired and connected to phone audio when I call the start() function.

Comment: Anyone ???????????????

Comment: @user32048403: Do you resolve your problem? I have same problem as your problem

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was looking for a way to connect the bluetooth device when user click a button if the user wants to use the bluetooth headset during a  Voip call.

My solution tested on Samsung S7 SM-G930F with android version 7.0 is:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity{

private AudioManager mAudioManager;
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.example_activity);

    initActivity();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
}

private void initActivity()
{
    initBroadcasrReceiver();
    initAudioManager();
}

private void initBroadcasrReceiver()
{
    mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED)) 
            {
                int scoAudioState = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);
                if(scoAudioState == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED)
                {
                    // This method should be called only after SCO is connected!
                    mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

private void initAudioManager()
{
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    resetSco();
    mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
}

private void resetSco()
{
    mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
    mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
    mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
    mAudioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(false);
}}
```

Once the SCO is connected you'll be able to hear and speak
from your bluetooth device.
Hope it helps.

Comment: If I setup "MODE_NORMAL" the output route is ALWAYS the loudspeaker, while the input route is ALWAYS (correctly) the headset microphone.

If I setup "MODE_IN_CALL" the output route is ALWAYS the headset, while the input route is OFTEN (not ALWAYS) the headset mic: sometimes the phone mic gets uncorrectly picked.

Any hint to solve this issue ? (using Android 11, Cat S62 Pro)

Comment: Have you tried ```AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION```?