# How can I start a call via Intent, but make sure it goes via Bluetooth Headset?

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, phone-call, headset

I can start a call with

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel://" + number));
  startActivity(intent);
```

But I want to make sure that when that call is started, it will be handled via the connected Bluetooth Headset, not via the phone's own mic and speaker. How can I do that? The solution can be specific to Samsung devices, if that helps.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give permission to the Maniefest in your application.

Here is the detailed answer about call via headset. But make sure you are connected with the bluetooth headset.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14993590/2931489

Comment: Is this solved? I followed the link, but that is a bit different. I should call `audioManager.startBluetoothSco(); audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);` after the startActivity?