# how to get voice data from bluetooth headset device in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

I am working on an application in which I have to fetch voice data in text format from my bluetooth headset.

[Using the Android RecognizerIntent with a bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset)

I am following above link but still i am unable to fetch voice from bluetooth headset.

Comment: Where you got stuck while referring above link code. If you get any error, then post logcat. Or post that part of code here.