# Bluetooth headset voice recognize not working

Tags: android, bluetooth, voice-recognition, headset

I am working on an application in which I have to recognize bluetooth headset voice. I have troubled a lot but still not get any solution.

I am following this link:

[Using the Android RecognizerIntent with a bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset)

And every time I m getting false from it 
mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(mContext, 
                                                    mHeadsetProfileListener, 
                                                    BluetoothProfile.HEADSET)

in startBluetooth11() method.

Please help.

Comment: did u  solved the issue?

Comment: Yes I have resolved this issue.

Comment: @SandeepPatidar How?