# How to keep bluetooth headset connection in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, speech-recognition

I am working on an application in which I have implemented speech recognition from bluetooth headset. It is working fine with single activity, but in my app there are 10 different activities and I want to create a singleton class of bluetooth connection which work in a whole application without losing connection.

I used implementation from [Using the Android RecognizerIntent with a bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset/14993590#14993590)

Comment: Implement a service with required functionality. See for details http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html