# How to make call using Intent using Bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, phone-call, headset

In my application I have to make call using Intent using Bluetooth Headset. Right now I am using below link.

I used implementation from [Using the Android RecognizerIntent with a bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset/14993590#14993590)

When calling dialog open Bluetooth Headset Connection going lost. Please help

Comment: What dialog do you mean?

Comment: Screen comes after make a call using Intent in that case bluetooth headset connection going lost