# How to acquire microphone audio via OPEN SL ES from a connected Bluetooth headset's microphone?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-ndk, opensl

I'm working an Android project about record and play from a connected Bluetooth headset's microphone. I need to use native code (Open SL ES). I referred [this answer of Hoan Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset/14993590#14993590) to write for connection Bluetooth (by Java). My results:

If I record and play using Java (Using `AudioRecord` for record and `AudioTrack` for play) => okay

If I record using native code => fail.

I also referred [this](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-ndk/15aptap8v8/how-do-you-acquire-microphone-audio-via-opensl-es-from-a-connected-bluetooth-headsets-microphone) but it was not finalized.

Does OpenSL ES not support bluetooth headset? Or Have I to write native code for connection Bluetooth?

Thanks!

Comment: Help me.............